# Return feedback from an event which is being waited on

Tags: c#, events, .net-3.5, event-handling

In it's simplicity what I am trying to do is handle "Doing Something" by firing off a process on a seperate thread to do what I need to do and waiting for an event to be raised to say "I have finished doing what I need to do". In the `EventArgs` though I will have a property for any errors which may be encountered during the process. Here is a simplified example of my situation.

```
public class MessageHandler
{
  private AutoResetEvent MessageHasSent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
  public void SendMessage()
  {
    MessageSender ms = new MessageSender();
    ms.MessageSent += new EventHandler<MessageSentEventArgs>(MessageHandler_MessageSent);

    Thread t = new Thread(ms.Send());
    t.Start();

    MessageHasSent.WaitOne();
    //Do some check here

    //Same again but for "Message recieved"
  }
  void MessageHandler_MessageSent(object sender, MessageSentEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Errors.Count != 0)
    {
      //What can I do here to return to the next step after waitone?
    }
    else
      MessageHasSent.Set();
  }
}
public class MessageSender
{
  public event EventHandler<MessageSentEventArgs> MessageSent;
  public void Send()
  {
    //Do some method which could potentiallialy return a List<Error>
    MessageSent(this, new MessageSentEventArgs() { Errors = new List<Error>() });
  }
}
public class Error { }
public class MessageSentEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public List<Error> Errors;
}
```

Essentially once the event has been raised from `Send` the code will continute, however I want some way of the event giving feedback, potentially using the `MessageHasSent`. I have tried different methods, I thought if I called `Close` instead of `Set` it would perhaps allow me to access something such as `IsClosed`. You could `throw an exception` or set a flag outside of the scope of the event to check but I feel like this is dirty.

Any suggestions?

Using the `TPL` isn't applicable in my case as I am using .NET 3.5.

Comment: You should use the TPL and the `Task` class instead.

Comment: Start here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx

Comment: If you're just going to block until the event is fired in the main thread what's the point of using events in the first place?  If you want to use an event based model you shouldn't do anything in the main thread after starting the async task; all of the result processing should be in the event handler.

Comment: @SLaks so I have been aproaching this from the wrong angle then in using what I have in my example code. The solution doesn't have to match my example code methodology, I am getting used to all these different classes for threads and events so any alternative code would be very helpful :)

Comment: @Servy I am blocking and waiting for something to finish because in my case, the `SendMessage` is a background worker `DoWork` event, so I am waiting for the events to be raised before continuing. As I have just mentioned I am new to trying to handle things like this so I understand I may not be taking the right aproach.

Comment: @LukeHennerley If you're actually using a background worker instead of using threads then please post your *actual* code.  If you're starting a thread from within the background thread...just don't.  Call the blocking version of the method directly from the `DoWork` handler since that's clearly how you want it to function.

Comment: OK, BackgroundWorker has RunWorkerCompleted event to which you can subscribe.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I have re-read what I am doing and also with Servy's comment come to the conclusion I am just doing a full circle. I am putting a method which will block on a thread, then waiting for it to return regardless. Why I am not JUST calling the method and waiting I don't know... It's a Friday, I think this has just been "One of them".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems that this entire section of code is already running in a background thread, and you're doing nothing more than starting up a new thread just so that you can wait for it to finish, you'd be better off just calling `Send` directly, rather than asynchronously.

- You don't need to fire off an event when you're completed.
- You don't need to signal the main thread when it needs to continue.
- You don't need to log the exceptions in a `List`, you can just throw them and catch them in `SendMessage` with a try/catch block.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
public class MessageHandler
{
    private AutoResetEvent MessageHasSent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private bool IsSuccess = false;
    public void SendMessage()
    {
        MessageSender ms = new MessageSender();
        ms.MessageSent += new EventHandler<MessageSentEventArgs>(MessageHandler_MessageSent);

        Thread t = new Thread(ms.Send());
        t.Start();

        MessageHasSent.WaitOne();
        if(IsSuccess)
            //wohooo
        else
            //oh crap

        //Same again but for "Message recieved"
    }
    void MessageHandler_MessageSent(object sender, MessageSentEventArgs e)
    {
        IsSuccess = e.Errors.Count == 0;
        MessageHasSent.Set();
    }
}
public class MessageSender
{
    public event EventHandler<MessageSentEventArgs> MessageSent;
    public void Send()
    {
        //Do some method which could potentiallialy return a List<Error>
        MessageSent(this, new MessageSentEventArgs() { Errors = new List<Error>() });
    }
}
public class Error { }
public class MessageSentEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public List<Error> Errors;
}
```

Comment: I mentioned this originially in the question - "could throw an exception or set a flag outside of the scope of the event to check but I feel like this is dirty." this will work but I was trying to see if there was a clever way I could return it. Further to comments on my question I can see what I am doing here is just a huge circle that isn't as smart as what I thought it was at the time...

Comment: sorry, overread that. I agree that its not very smart exactly like that, but in some conditions its the way to go...